# sudo apt-get install & sudo apt-get -f install returning error

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-center, dpkg

Every time I try to install any package, I get the same error. It refers to the same dependencies with any package. this causes the software center to crash.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sync-my-l2p:i386 : Depends: libqt5core5a:i386 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not    installed
                    Depends: libqt5gui5:i386 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed or
                             libqt5gui5-gles:i386 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libqt5network5:i386 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libqt5widgets5:i386 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libqt5xml5:i386 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

The same happens every time I try to install any packages.

Output

```
    laptop:~$ apt-mark showhold
    laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install sync-my-l2p:i386 libqt5core5a:i386 libqt5gui5:i386 libqt5network5:i386 libqt5widgets5:i386 libqt5xml5:i386
[sudo] password: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
sync-my-l2p:i386 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5core5a:i386 : Depends: libicu52:i386 (>= 52~m1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5gui5:i386 : Depends: libegl1-mesa:i386 (>= 7.8.1) or
                            libegl1-x11:i386
                   Depends: libgbm1:i386 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgles2-mesa:i386 (>= 7.8.1) or
                            libgles2:i386
                   Depends: libqt5dbus5:i386 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-icccm4:i386 (>= 0.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-image0:i386 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-keysyms1:i386 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-randr0:i386 (>= 1.3) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-render-util0:i386 (>= 0.3.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-shape0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-xfixes0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb-xkb1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0:i386 (>= 0.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5network5:i386 : Depends: libqt5dbus5:i386 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

A new error encountered !!!

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: Do you get any output from `apt-mark showhold`? Else try `sudo apt-get install sync-my-l2p:i386 libqt5core5a:i386 libqt5gui5:i386 libqt5network5:i386 libqt5widgets5:i386 libqt5xml5:i386` and paste its output.

Comment: apt-mark showhold : returns nothing.
sudo apt-get install : returns the same along with few more dependencies.
how to add the output. It is too long for the comment.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and paste the output.

Comment: the output shows dependencies of following packages.
libqt5core5a:i386 : Depends: libicu52:i386, libegl1-mesa:i386 (>= 7.8.1),libegl1-x11:i386,libgbm1:i386,libgles2-mesa:i386,libqt5dbus5:i386,libxcb-icccm4:i386,libxcb-image0:i386,libxcb-keysyms1:i386,libxcb-randr0:i386,libxcb-render-util0:i386,libxcb-shape0:i386,libxcb-xfixes0:i386,libxcb-xkb1:i386,libxkbcommon-x11-0:i386,libqt5network5:i386 : Depends: libqt5dbus5:i386

Comment: Did you try installing libqt5gui5 or upgrading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As apt-get is not able to install the dependencies, i think you have installed the software for wrong architecture. try to purge the  `sync-my-l2p`. you could use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge sync-my-l2p
sudo dpkg -P sync-my-l2p
```

then use:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If you want to install sync-my-l2p again, try to find the amd64 version.

Regards

Comment: Yes this seemed to work.  It works now.. Thanks mate..

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade **libqt5gui5** using `sudo apt-get upgrade libqt5gui5`.

Comment: yes. I tried installing every dependency along with the one mentioned above. But every apt-get install return the same dependency list. 
So basically, every apt-get install/upgrade isn't working!! :(